# Using wxWidgets from a DLL

Tags: wxwidgets

Is it possible to use wxWidgets from a DLL?
I'm writing a plugin of sorts. (ACM for use in VirtualDub in this case, but I have other projects where I would like to do a similar thing)

All the docs that I come across discuss wxWidgets from the point of view of an executable.
In most of these cases, I don't have access to the executable's source, but I'm writing various libraries for use in the process space of these executables.

Ideally, I would like to perform the minimum startup required to get wxWidgets up and running in a DLL.
Which probably means performing some initialization, and starting a message pump, but without advertising an entry point for wxWidgets to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using wxWidgets 2.9.2, all you need to do is the following:

```
wxApp::SetInstance(new wxApp());
new wxInitializer();
```

Then delete the wxInitializer when you are finished with it. Though I still cannot find this documented anywhere...

Comment: I'm amazed that I didn't find anything else out there. I'll try to verify it, but it's rather hard to find the time.